# How I can use Laravel Passport Auth without Vue Component

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I have installed Passport Auth in Laravel 5.3 using this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport

but I have followed the steps before "Frontend Quickstart" heading now I have a API route:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    //return $request->user();
    return json_encode(array(
      1 => "John",
      2 => "Mary",
      3 => "Steven"
    ));
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

and I am trying to hit api url via postman `http://localhost/project/public/api/user`

with Headers: `Accept: application/json`

It shows me this output:

```
{"error":"Unauthenticated."}
```

*Please tell me how I can authenticate my API with passport auth? Also how I can generate access_token for authorization?*

Comment: Matt Stauffer had written an excellent tutorial on `laravel/passport`, which should help you out: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-passport

Comment: `access_token` generation depends in where do you want to use your API. A third application will have access to your API? An user will have access to your API? If that is the case, this user is registered in the Laravel API application database or in a third application database?

Comment: @craig_h, can you tell me how I can generate client_id and client_secret in the passport auth without Vue component? because without client_id and client_secret how I can authenticate users to access API

Comment: I realize this is very old, but hit this upon googling. So, here's the answer to your last comment, in case anyone else lands here from the big G: `php artisan passport:client --password`